# SQL Server create bitset larger than POWER(2,30)

Tags: sql-server, bit-manipulation

```
select POWER(2,31)
select CAST(POWER(2,31) as bigint)
```

both result in the error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 2147483648.000000.
```

I have need to generate a bitmask that exceeds 64 bits.  How can I do this in SQL Server?  (I'm using SQL Server 2008, but if it's only possible in 2012+, I'd like to know that too)

Comment: It looks like I can't do any better than 2^62, which isn't good enough.  I'll have to break my inputs into two smaller values and create two complementary bitsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375254)**

```
SELECT CAST(POWER(2.0,31.0) AS DECIMAL(38,0))
```

**EDIT:**

Probably the best approach will be to create custom tally table with precalculated values:

```
╔═════╦═════════════════════╗
║  n  ║       Power_2^n     ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ 1                   ║
║ 2   ║ 2                   ║
║ 3   ║ 8                   ║
║ 4   ║ 16                  ║
║ 5   ║ 32                  ║
║ ... ║ ...                 ║
║ 62  ║ 4611686018427387904 ║
║ ... ║ ...                 ║
╚═════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, lad225, for the attempt, but it simply looks like it can't be done as I was hoping, and I need to re-think how I tackle this.

Comment: @Dan Probably spliting to 32-bit should be the best, or you can try with CLR function

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would do this via CLR?

Comment: @Dan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx + use mathematical library for .NET

Comment: @Dan Even simpler, just create table with power from 1 to 100 and store it. There is no need to calculate it ever time you need it.

Comment: A special-purpose tally table.  I like it.  Could you post that as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: When I'm finished, I'll post my implementation of this, for others.

Comment: Actually, can't go any higher than 62, because there is no datatype capable of handling that without data errors...

Answer (score 1):

Ack, found this on SQL Server Central (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic619623-338-1.aspx):

```
select POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT),CAST(31 AS BIGINT))
```

Comment: You wrote `"I have need to generate a bitmask that exceeds 64 bits"`.This will fail with >64

Comment: Actually, if I'm looking for accuracy, so does yours.  My solution can handle up to `POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT),CAST(62 AS BIGINT))`, which results in `4611686018427387904`.  `select CAST(POWER(2.0,62.0) as DECIMAL(38,0)) ` results in `4611686018427387900`

Comment: Check again https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375258, they give the same answer

Comment: Yes, and both wrong.  The demo returns `4611686018427388000`, which rounds the last 4 digits to 8000 instead of `7900` or `7904`.